# Detecting camera's height and width in a React Native mobile app

Tags: javascript, react-native, camera, base64, android-camera

I am using the `react-native-camera` package to make photos inside a React Native Mobile app.

Within the React Native part of the app I use [Base64](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base64) format to encode the images and [ImageStore](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/imagestore.html) to store them.

The question is, how can I get information about the camera's resolution (height, width) within React Native / Javascript?

- Either directly from the camera, or by accessing the height or width
  attributes of the photo...
- I tried specifying the resolution manually, but the `react-native-camera`'s [setting](https://github.com/lwansbrough/react-native-camera) `captureQuality={Camera.constants.CaptureQuality["1080p"]}` does not seem to work
  (tested on Android) and the camera still uses full resolution.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, `react-native-camera` doesn't have the option to set width/height on capture nor after getting the response. However if you apply this **Android Only** [PR](https://github.com/lwansbrough/react-native-camera/pull/439/commits/d91afe4d5939fa6846947bc2ed6d992ac940c72c) manually to `/node_modules/react-native-camera` (or install his fork via npm) you can get the width/height of the captured photo in response.

Also, if you like, you can resize the photo you captured as explained [here](https://github.com/lwansbrough/react-native-camera/issues/119#issuecomment-156320472).